# Panel opacity should change the indicators' menu opacity, is this a valid bug?

Tags: unity, compiz

In Ubuntu 11.04 with unity 3.8.16-0ubuntu1~natty1 when clicking an indicator its icon turns opaque and the menu shown is also opaque, regardless of the panel opacity value. I think both the icon when clicked and the menu should follow the value set by Panel Opacity in CCSM.
Is this a valid bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is somewhat of a valid bug, except that the menus are controlled by a separate plugin. To make menus transparent (to some extent) use the following values:

[image]

Comment: I think using the same value for transparency makes the desktop more consistent, and I find it confusing to be able to change opacity values with two separate plugins. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @Santiago, you were asking whether this could be considered a valid bug. If you decide to file it on Launchpad, do you think you could post a link to the bug report back here for reference?

Comment: I've already filed it in Launchpad, here's the link https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/804893