# Full Transparent (glass type) menu for ubuntu 14.04

Tags: unity, 14.04, indicator, menu

Is it possible to have menus like this concept design in ubuntu 14.04?
with static blur like dash,launcher?

[image]

Comment: Not yet... but there will be bro... :) http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/04/indicator-menus-re-imagined-unity-style

Comment: For just transparency: http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2013/08/transparent-panel-titlebar-ubuntu-unity/ http://askubuntu.com/questions/51550/panel-opacity-should-change-the-indicators-menu-opacity-is-this-a-valid-bug

Comment: @Naveen Yes!, That is what inspired me to create this concept design...as this one is much familiar with unity than the one in that link, also it is an old post, (2012!)

Comment: @Mateo thanks for the link :)

I just want to know if it is possible to have blur in indicator-menus...transparency makes everything transparent (including menu text) but it is not what I expect...